# Conservation of angular momentum in pair annihilation in scalar QED

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conservation-laws, quantum-electrodynamics, scattering-cross-section

Suppose we have the usual scalar QED for a massive charged field $\phi$ ,

$$\mathcal L=-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}+(D_\mu\phi)^\dagger(D^\mu\phi)-m^2\phi^\dagger\phi$$

with $g^{\mu\nu}=\text{diag}(1,-1,-1,-1)$ and $D_\mu=\partial_\mu+iqA_\mu$. This theory has then two interaction vertices, in the picture below. (most people put a factor of 2 on the second vertex but I like to think about combinatorics only at the end so I skip it)[image: vertices of scalar QED]

Now, if we wanted to compute the cross-section for the process

$$\phi_1+\bar\phi_2\rightarrow\gamma_3+\gamma_4$$

to lowest order in $q$ we get the three diagrams (time flows to the right)

[image: diagrams of annihilation]

and if we use the Feynman rules for the vertices that I've written above, we get for the matrix element of the process

$$M=4q^2\left[\frac{(p_1\cdot\epsilon_3^*)(p_2\cdot\epsilon_4^*)}{t-m^2}+\frac{(p_1\cdot\epsilon_4^*)(p_2\cdot\epsilon_3^*)}{u-m^2}+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_3^*\cdot\epsilon_4^*\right].$$

Great. This satisfies the Ward identity (before we use Lorenz gauge conditions or the mass-shell for the photons, both of which I've already substituted here) and everything seems fine. But this has a problem. Putting everything in spherical coordinates in the center of mass frame, using circular polarization, and going through with computations we eventually get for the mod-square matrix element

$$|M|^2=4q^4\left[\frac{(s/4-m^2)\sin^2\theta}{s/4\sin^2\theta+m^2\cos^2\theta}-\delta_{\lambda_3\lambda_4}\right]^2$$

Notice how $|M|^2\neq0$ for $\lambda_3\neq\lambda_4$. This is a clear violation of conservation of angular momentum! This can be avoided if, in the first vertex, instead of $k+k'$ we used $k-k'$ or something similar. This, however, is inconsistent with the Lagrangian, and would also render the contributions from the first two diagrams null. There must be something I'm missing here.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/377469/why-is-the-scalar-qed-vertex-not-inconsistent-with-angular-momentum-conservation

Comment: I wonder if it is just Orbital Angular momentum that is in play here?

Comment: @Darkseid Maybe, but I don't see how it would show up since everything is in the CM frame

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given the infinitesimal version of rotation:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \theta}
= \left({\cal{J}}_z\right)^\mu_{\; \nu} x^\nu \left( \partial_\mu \phi \right)
= x \partial_y \phi - y \partial_x \phi,
\end{equation}
the Noether current is:
\begin{align}
J_z^\mu & \equiv
  \sum_n \frac{\partial {\cal{L}}}{\partial \left( \partial_\mu{\phi_n} \right)}
  \frac{\partial \phi_n}{\partial \alpha} \\
& = \left( \partial^\mu \phi^* - i q A^\mu \phi^* \right) \left(  x \partial_y \phi - y \partial_x \phi \right) + h.c.
\end{align}

With the usual field operator expansion:
\begin{align}
\phi & = \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2 \pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \omega_p}}
  \left( a_p e^{-i p \cdot x} + b^\dagger_p e^{i p \cdot x} \right), \\
\phi^* & = \int \frac{d^3 p}{(2 \pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \omega_p}}
  \left( b_p e^{-i p \cdot x} + a^\dagger_p e^{i p \cdot x} \right),
\end{align}
the Noether charge for the rotation around z-axis is (after a bit of algebra, and with the gauge choice of $A^0 = 0$):
\begin{align}
J_z & = \int d^3 x J_z^0 \\
& = \frac{1}{2} \int d^3x \int \frac{d^3p}{(2 \pi)^3} \frac{d^3q}{(2 \pi)^3} \sqrt{\frac{\omega_p}{\omega_q}}
  \left( x^1 q_2 - x^2 q_1 \right)
  \left( b^\dagger_q b_p e^{i (q - p) \cdot x} + a^\dagger_p a_q e^{-i (q - p) \cdot x} \right) + h.c.
\end{align}

Naturally the expectation value of this operator on particle/anti-particle state $|k, \overline{k}\rangle$ could be checked to be $0$.

The operator $J_z$ itself does not kill the state, however. Which means that in the basis of $J_z$'s eigenstates $|k, \overline{k}\rangle$ has non-zero coefficients. Therefore the scattering from your question might pick those states to produce two polarized vector particles.

The deviation is:
\begin{align}
\langle k, \overline{k} | (L_z)^2 | k, \overline{k} \rangle =
  \frac{1}{2} \int d^3x \int d^3y
  \left(x^1 k_2 - x^2 k_1 \right) \left(y^1 k_2 - y^2 k_1 \right) = \infty
\end{align}
confirming that the pair of particles has an infinite spectrum of orbital angular momenta in z- direction as long as either of $k_1$ or $k_2$ momentum is non-zero.

Thus the pair of vector particles created from annihilation of particle and anti-particle must have zero polarization sum only for $phi = 0$. For other scattering angles there is non-zero amplitude for producing non-zero total polarization (angular momentum).

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize it was that simple. It was just a matter of thinking non-classically (as it always is, haha). Thanks!

Comment: This should allowed classically too, if one would think in terms of ensembles of particles.

Comment: Yes, I was just thinking too much of the state as being localized on the axis of motion, when in reality it's uniformly distributed over all impact parameters.

Comment: Exactly! This was not obvious to me before I worked through the solution. You asked a great question.